# Scrolling inside a form in Watir

Tags: ruby, scroll, watir

I am running a test on a web app using Ruby-Watir-Rspec. It is very simple since I'm a beginner.
I open a form and enter the required information, but the "Create" button is not in the visible area, so I get the message:

```
Failure/Error: @browser.button(class: xxx).click

     Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException:
       element located, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Button: located: true; {:class=>xxx, :tag_name=>"button"}> to be present

Caused by:
     # Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError:
     #   element not interactable
```

If I scroll while the script is running, it clicks on the button and the test is successful. 
I tried scroll.to, wait_until_present, scroll to coordinates, scroll_into_view, none of them worked.
The only way to make it work was to put " @browser.send_keys :tab" several times until it reaches the button at the bottom of the form.

I believe the problem is the button being **inside the form** which does not take the entire page (behind the form is the map so that part of the page doesn't have the scrolling option)...so is there some way to scroll inside the form? Or do you know some other approach to finding this button? Any hint is appreciated.
Btw, the page is maximized.

Here is the code snippet, just simple:

```
it 'should create the place' do
    @browser.button(class: xxx).click
end
```

Comment: It says ElementNotVisibleError, could it be that you disable the button until require fields are filled in the form? And in your test you're not filling all the require fields before you do button click

Comment: I am filling the form(required fields) in the rest of the test which works fine, this is just the last step in the test - the one that's not working

Comment: Can you provide the (minimal amount of) HTML to reproduce the behavior?  Or provide a test link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is a custom scrollable element that hides the content with the `overflow: hidden` style. Elements in the overflow are not considered visible/present. When you manually scroll, you're bringing the element out of the overflow so that it's present.

I've seen a couple of these in the past. Each one needed a different approach for scrolling. Without the exact HTML/CSS, it's hard to say how to scroll the element.

However, if you're not trying to test the scrolling, you could manually fire the click event. This will bypass the visibility requirements:

```
@browser.button(class: xxx).click!
```

Comment: I tried to fire the click event and it worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Watir Scroll gem: https://github.com/p0deje/watir-scroll and scrolling the element to the center of the viewport: `button.scroll.to :center`.

You can also submit the form directly `@browser.form.submit`

Comment: I already tried Watir Scroll gem and button.scroll.to:center, didn't work.
The other approach I didn't know for, just tried it, the script was successful but the page sends me "We are sorry, something went wrong"
Thank you for you answer!